# Font-awesome icons not correctly positioned in the footer

Tags: html, css, footer, font-awesome

I have a `footer` on my website.

I want to have the icons to be  center (both vertically and horizontally), and for the colored area to be:

- Always at the bottom of the screen
- Not much taller than the icons

Code:

```css
#footer {
  background: #0e0e0e;
  border-top: 0px solid #0e0e0e;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="color color-secondary short">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 center">
        <ul class="social-icons mb-md">
          <li class="social-icons-fa-github"><a href="https://github.com" target="_blank" title="GitHub"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="social-icons-linkedin"><a href="www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="social-icons-stack-overflow"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

What it looks like with this code:

[image: Here's my footer, with the space below the icons]

I have changed the `padding`, `margin`, and `height` in  `px` values a few times, and couldn't achieve the desired result.

Edit: Dippas' code works, but I had to modify some more existing CSS code - it came out as:

```
#footer .container .row > div {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: -23px; }
```

Now my footer is at the bottom, with pixel-perfect distances defined!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `flexbox` by applying `display:flex` and `justify-content: center` to `ul` you can achieve what you want.

**OP Comment**

> Ah, that's a neat feature. I like the look of 1.2em;. However, I'm
>   still left with the issue of the footer being too tall. I'd like it to
>   be about twice as tall as the icons, with them in the centre.

So, use `align-items:center` from `flexbox` to align vertically, plus some `height`, I choosed `2em`, feel free to choose whatever you like the most.

```css
#footer {
  background: #0e0e0e;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#footer ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  height:2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}
#footer li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<footer id="footer" class="color color-secondary short">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 center">
        <ul class="social-icons mb-md">
          <li class="social-icons-fa-github"><a href="https://github.com" target="_blank" title="GitHub"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="social-icons-linkedin"><a href="www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="social-icons-stack-overflow"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I want to make the footer thinner, so I changed "margin: 0;" to "margin: -30px;". Increasing this further does decrease the height, but the position of the icons remains the same. I'd like them to be in the centre of this footer, whatever its height.

Comment: just decrease the `font-size` of the footer or the icons. dont mess with `margins`, instead of  `font-size: .9em;` try change to `font-size: .6em;`, you will see the difference

Comment: Ah, that's a neat feature. I like the look of 1.2em;. However, I'm still left with the issue of the footer being too tall. I'd like it to be about twice as tall as the icons, with them in the centre.

Comment: you said in your question ***Not much taller than the icons*** thats why I did with no height at all, but I can update my answer

Comment: That'd be fantastic, dippas. Although, at the moment, (for me at least!) the footer bar seems to be more than three times taller than the icon height.

Comment: "align-items:center;" does help with the aesthetics, though I'm still desiring for a footer that's less tall.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115640/discussion-between-idios-and-dippas).

Answer (score 2):

## Absolute container and transform it in place

Chaning the ul element with class `.social-icons`:

- `positiom:absolute;` so we can position it inside the footer `#footer`.
- `top:50%;` `left:50%;` so its in the middle both horizontal and vertical
- `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` because positions are calculated from the top left.

```css
#footer {
  background: #0e0e0e;
  border-top: 0px solid #0e0e0e;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  clear: both;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px; /*Display property can be changed*/
}
#footer .social-icons {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#footer li {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  /*For display only*/
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
<footer id="footer" class="color color-secondary short">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 center">
        <ul class="social-icons mb-md">
          <li class="social-icons-fa-github"><a href="https://github.com" target="_blank" title="GitHub"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="social-icons-linkedin"><a href="www.linkedin.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li class="social-icons-stack-overflow"><a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" title="Linkedin"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```